# Is the reminder that "Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow" supposed to appear on all sites?

Tags: discussion

The main Stack Overflow site has the following reminder in the *Your Answer* box:

> **Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)

Whereas on the Electrical Engineering site the above reminder doesn't appear in the *Your Answer* box (checked when both logged in and when an anonymous user).

Currently I have no desire to use *Artificial Intelligence tools* to get information, but just wondering if there is a deliberate reason for why the above reminder isn't shown on the Electrical Engineering site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stack Exchange site has features that the sub sites don't have, it's the most-used site and gets the most attention. There isn't a deliberate reason. My guess is they don't have the analytics to detect AI questions on this site or haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: I noticed [Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395881/sites-can-now-request-to-enable-a-banner-to-warn-about-their-policy-on-ai-genera) has appeared on the main meta site. Not sure if worth doing that on the Electrical Engineering site.